# Parsing mixfix expression in antlr3

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr3

I need to adapt an ANTLR3 grammar to support let expressions. The operator needs to bind very weakly. For instance `let x=3 in x + 1` reads as `let x=3 in (x+1)` rather than as `(let x=3 in x) + 1`.

My candidate grammar is still ambiguous, unfortunately.
Is there a standard way to make the rules unambiguous?
(With extra `( )` it works.)

Btw, it seems to work of the box with ANTLR4. However, this is not an option in my case.

```
grammar Expr;

prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE
    |   NEWLINE
    ;

expr:   sum ( ('*'|'/') sum )* ;

sum:    atom ( ('+'|'-') atom )* ;

atom:   INT
    |   ID
    |   '(' expr ')'
 // |   '(' let ')'
    |   let
    ;

let:    'let' ID '=' expr 'in' expr ;

ID  :   ('a' .. 'z')+ ;
INT :   ('0' ..'9')+ ;
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n' ;
WS  :   ' ' { $channel = HIDDEN; };
```

Comment: It should also be that `3 * let x = 2 in x+1` is the same as `3 * (let x=2 in x+1)`.

Comment: I have tried setting `options { greedy = true; }`, but perhaps not in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem.

Parsed tree for the input

```
let x=3 in x + 1
3 * let x = 2 in x+1
```

is

[image: Parsed tree]

Comment: I do get an error (or warning) message: `Decision can match input such as "{'*', '/'}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2` etc. Apparently, the parser happens to do what I want it to do, but that seems to be by coincidence. It resolves the ambiguous situation in my favour. Lucky!

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is to have a different non-terminal for each precedence level, like this (note that you seem to have sum and produce precedence reversed, so I fixed that too):

```
expr:   sum | let;

let:    'let' ID '=' expr 'in' expr ;

sum:    product ( ('+'|'-') prodcut)* ;

product: atom ( ('*'|'/') atom )* ;

atom:   INT
    |   ID
    |   '(' expr ')'
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply! Am I mistaken in thinking that this grammar does not accept `3 + let x=2 in x` ?

Comment: Yes.  Allowing that would be strange, and a little gross:  you have a special kind of atom, that can only appear at the end of a special kind of product, that can only appear at the end of a special kind of sum.

Comment: Maybe it's strange, but that is how the target language is designed. I have tried adding "special" rules mentioning let in more places, but it did not work out w/o conflict.

Comment: Then you probably want to live with an ambiguous grammar.  The normal default rule is to settle a shift-reduce conflict in favor of the shift, which can usually be made to work.